# Laravel filesize of a filethat is uploaded to Storage folder

Tags: php, laravel

How can i get the file size of a file stored in the storage folder? `$fileFullPath` leads to correct path but `$size = Storage::size($fileFullPath)` fires the exception: `File not found at path`.

```
public function getFromStorage()
{
  $contents = Storage::disk('local')->get('txtFiles/file.txt');
  $fileFullPath = Storage::disk('local')->path('txtFiles/file.txt');
  $size = Storage::size($fileFullPath);
  dd( $fileFullPath) // return correct path
  dd( $size) // return file not found
 }
```

Comment: How about `Storage::disk('local')->size($fileFullPath)`? Does that work? If so, your `local` disk is not your *default* disk.

Comment: File not found at path

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`size($file)` does not expect the full path, but the relative path. Try:

```
$size = Storage::disk('local')->size('txtFiles/file.txt');
```